# Domain redirect domain/domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

i have a wordpress with multisite. I redirected my domain to my host and now, when i check my website, my urls are domain.com/domain.com/wp-contents/[...]

In my console, the same :

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://example.com/example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08...

Here is my .htaccess :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPresshtaccess
```

I tried to remove htaccess. And i dont have access to wp-admin be cause always redirected.

Any idea ?

Comment: What is the site_url and home_url constant in wp_config.php

Comment: @TurtleTread : have no  site_url and no home_url but have

define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'example.com');

I tried to add your constant but change nothing

Comment: Sorry, WP_SITEURL just for single sites. So did you choose the subdomain or subfolder installation? If subfolder, is example.com your site folder name?

Comment: using subfolder by using x2 different child child themes. First site is example.com and the second example.com/subscribers. Before change domain, works perfectly. I changed all my URL in database

Comment: did you change domain or just move to different server? check out this https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_WordPress_Multisite

Comment: @TurtleTread i just changed the domain "developpment" url to "customer" url. The server didn't changed.

Comment: @TurtleTread thanks for your help, i find the solution.

Comment: yea redirect problems usually has to do with these url's don't have http in front of it. Lots of people had this issue before which is why I asked about your siteurl constants. anyways, glad you solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the problem was on database wp_1_options was "example.com" and i changed for "http://example.com".